# EL expression for getter without a get prefix

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, el

We are using JAXB-generated classes, including an Enum. JAXB generated an Enum for us that looks like this. Note, the getter does **not** have a "get" in its method name.

```
public enum ActionType {

    A("A"),
    B("B"),
    C("C");

    private final String value;

    ActionType(String v)
    {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }   

    public ActionType fromValue(String v)
    {
        for (ActionType c: ActionType.values())
        {
            if (c.value.equals("v")) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

I'm having problems referencing this in a JSTL Expression. This does not work:

```
             <c:forEach var="item" items="${action_types}">
                <form:radiobutton path="actionType" value="${item.value}"/>${item.value}
            </c:forEach>
```

Error:

**Property 'value' not found on type ....ActionType**

It's looking for **getValue()** rather than **value()** that we have auto-generated. Any workarounds?

Comment: Excellent this worked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on EL 2.2+ which introduced the new feature of invoking direct methods with the parentheses syntax like so `#{bean.method()}`, then just utilize that feature.

```
<form:radiobutton ... value="${item.value()}" />
```

EL 2.2 was introduced with Servlet 3.0 (December 2009). Tomcat 7 was the first to support it. So if you're on Tomcat 7+ and your webapp's `web.xml` is compatible with Servlet 3.0+, then it should just work.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution if you're using an old EL version is to create a custom `BeanInfo` class (`ActionTypeBeanInfo` in this case) in the same package as your enum with the correct `PropertyDescriptor` for `value`.

```
public class ActionTypeBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {

  public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors() {
    try {
      Method readMethod = ActionType.class.getDeclaredMethod("value", new Class[0]); // not getValue
      Method writeMethod = null;     
      PropertyDescriptor value = new PropertyDescriptor("value", readMethod, writeMethod);
      return new PropertyDescriptor[] { value };
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```